# How to modify the plot when ggpredict() is used

Tags: r

The ggpredict() function is part of the ggeffects package. I like to change the names of the coefficients in the following plot:

```
lme1<- lme(mpg ~ cyl +  disp + hp,
           random = ~1|disp, method = "ML", data=mtcars)

plot(ggpredict(lme1, terms = c("cyl", "disp", "hp[80,150,215]")))
```

[image]

How to change the name of the y and x axis can be achieved by adding "labs(x = "Number of cylinders",
y = "Miles/(US) gallon")".

```
 plot(ggpredict(lme1, terms = c("cyl", "disp", "hp[80,150,215]"))) +
 labs(x = "Number of cylinders",
       y = "Miles/(US) gallon")
```

But how can the third coefficients "hp" be changed into e.g. "Gross horsepower"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* build the plot by yourself, and then use a custom [labeller-function](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labeller.html). Another solution might be the [ggggeffects-package](https://github.com/mattansb/ggggeffects), which provides utilities to build own plots.

The package maintainer has proposed [two solutions](https://github.com/mattansb/ggggeffects/issues/1):

```r
library(ggggeffects)
#> Loading required package: ggeffects
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(nlme)

lme1<- lme(mpg ~ cyl +  disp + hp,
           random = ~1|disp, method = "ML", data=mtcars)

gge <- ggpredict(lme1, terms = c("cyl", "disp", "hp[80,150,215]"))

hp_labeller <- as_labeller(c("80" = "Gross horsepower = 80",
                             "150" = "Gross horsepower = 150",
                             "215" = "Gross horsepower = 215"))

autoplot(gge, labeller = labeller(hp = hp_labeller)) +
  geom_expected_line() +
  geom_CI_ribbon() +
  labs(x = "Number of cylinders",
       y = "Miles/(US) gallon")
```

[image]

```r
library(ggeffects)
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)

lme1<- lme(mpg ~ cyl +  disp + hp,
           random = ~1|disp, method = "ML", data=mtcars)

gge <- ggpredict(lme1, terms = c("cyl", "disp", "hp[80,150,215]"))

p <- plot(gge)

hp_labeller <- as_labeller(c("hp = 80" = "Gross horsepower = 80",
                             "hp = 150" = "Gross horsepower = 150",
                             "hp = 215" = "Gross horsepower = 215"))

p + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(facet),
             labeller = labeller(facet = hp_labeller))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rename the column before plotting?

```
library(dplyr)
library(nlme)
library(ggeffects)

df <- mtcars
df <- df %>% rename(Horse_Power = hp)
lme1<- lme(mpg ~ cyl +  disp + Horse_Power,
           random = ~1|disp, method = "ML", data=df)

plot(ggpredict(lme1, terms = c("cyl", "disp", "Horse_Power[80,150,215]")))
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, of cause to change the name before plotting is a possibility. However is there also a way to do it while plotting?

Comment: You _could_ build the plot by yourself, and then use a custom [labeller-function](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labeller.html). Another solution might be the [ggggeffects-package](https://github.com/mattansb/ggggeffects), which provides utilities to build own plots.